# JavaScript conflict with googleapi

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JavaScript in html.

Here is it: (for my website scrolling notice use).

```
<script>
JQ = $;
function JQ(element){
    if(arguments.length>1){
        for(var i=0,length=arguments.length,elements=[];i<length;i++){
    elements.push(JQ(arguments[i]));
    }
    return elements;
    }
    if(typeof element=="string"){
        return document.getElementById(element);
    }else{
        return element;
    }
}
var Class={
    create:function(){
        return function(){
            this.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
        }
    }
}
Function.prototype.bind=function(object){
    var method=this;
    return function(){
        method.apply(object,arguments);
    }
}
var Scroll=Class.create();
Scroll.prototype={
    initialize:function(element,height){
        this.element=JQ(element);
        this.element.innerHTML+=this.element.innerHTML;
        this.height=height;
        this.maxHeight=this.element.scrollHeight/2;
        this.counter=0;
        this.scroll();
        this.timer="";
        this.element.onmouseover=this.stop.bind(this);
        this.element.onmouseout=function(){this.timer=setTimeout(this.scroll.bind(this),1000);}.bind(this);
    },
    scroll:function(){
        if(this.element.scrollTop<this.maxHeight){
            this.element.scrollTop++;
            this.counter++;
        }else{
            this.element.scrollTop=0;
            this.counter=0;
        }
        if(this.counter<this.height){
            this.timer=setTimeout(this.scroll.bind(this),22);
        }else{
            this.counter=0;
            this.timer=setTimeout(this.scroll.bind(this),3126);
        }
    },
    stop:function(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }
}
var myscroll=new Scroll("myscroll",13);
</script>
```

After that, I would like to add a jquery function for my website also, but it will conflict with my other js when I including jquery from googleapi. I have search the solution, add something like `jQuery.noConflict();` but it still can't works. 
Below is the coding after I add into html, have JS error. Drop-down menu all can't work.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    jq(function(){
        jq("#paysubmitbtn").click(function(){
           if(jq("#paymount").val() >= $minco){
                jq("#error").text("({lang jncashout:text_07}"+parseInt(jq("#paymount").val()*$exco*$jsuse)+"$jifentitle {lang jncashout:text_08}"+jq("#paymount").val()*$exco*$chargeco1+"$jifentitle {lang jncashout:text_09})");
             }else{
             jq("#error").text("({lang jncashout:text_10}"+$minco+"$cashoutname)");
             return false;
           }
        });
    });

    jq(function(){
          jq("#paymount").blur(function(){
             if(jq("#paymount").val() >= $minco){
                    jq("#error").text("({lang jncashout:text_07}"+parseInt(jq("#paymount").val()*$exco*$jsuse)+"$jifentitle {lang jncashout:text_08}"+jq("#paymount").val()*$exco*$chargeco1+"$jifentitle {lang jncashout:text_09})");
                 }else{
                   jq("#error").text("({lang jncashout:text_10}"+$minco+"$cashoutname)");
                 }
          });

       });
</script>
```

I check the error from google chrome console display

```
Uncaught TypeError: ctrlObj.getAttribute is not a function common.js?kkZ:1243 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeChild is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: ctrlObj.getAttribute is not a function
```

I am really no well in JS, please help me to solve the problem where I need to improve, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see `ctrlObj` in the snippet you provided.

But just to let you know  `getAttribute()` javascript method.

So if `ctrlObj` is a jquery object it may not work well with `getAttribute`. So 
in that case you can use jQuery `.attr` method.

Example

var x = ctrlObj.attr('your attribute name');

Comment: I use an third party php forum software, the `getAttribute` was came from the php software, file name is common.js. So if I don't want to edit any default document, is it possible to improve the coding related with `http://ajax.googleapis.com` that one? thank you